# Performing arithmetic on double

Tags: ios, double, nsdecimalnumber

I have an app whose purpose is to compare chronologically ordered time intervals, which are stored by Core Data (via MagicalRecord) as attributes of type double, on an entity called `TimedActivity`. Ordering directions are supplied by attributes called `activityOfInterest` and `benchmarkActivity` on another entity named `SearchSpecs`. The scheme may seem a bit overcomplicated since I'm pretty green, but that part of it works.

The problem is that getting percentages from two doubles appears to be a bit of a runaround, at least according to the research I've done. I don't need extreme precision. Round seconds are fine. I found a suggestion relating to the use of `NSDecimalNumber`, but it too seemed like a long way around the corner.

Here is the relevant code in it's current state, with pseudocode to indicate my problem area:

```
#pragma mark - Go button case handlers

-(void) handleAvsAAction
{
//    NSArray *searchSpecsObjects = [SearchSpecs MR_findAll];
//    NSLog(@"SearchSpecs number of objects is %i",[searchSpecsObjects count]);

    NSArray *searchSpecsArray = [SearchSpecs MR_findAll];
    NSLog(@"searchSpecsArray count is %i", [searchSpecsArray count]);

    SearchSpecs *thisSpec = [searchSpecsArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"SearchSpec activityOfInterest should be %@", thisSpec.activityOfInterest);
    NSLog(@"SearchSpec benchmarkActivity should be %@", thisSpec.benchmarkActivity);

    //    NSArray *activityOfInterestArray;
//    NSArray *benchmarkActivityArray;
    NSNumber *activityOfInterestDurationTotal;
    NSNumber *benchmarkActivityDurationTotal;

    NSPredicate *activityOfInterestPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == '%@'",thisSpec.activityOfInterest];

    NSPredicate *benchmarkActivityPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == '%@'", thisSpec.benchmarkActivity];

    activityOfInterestDurationTotal = [TimedActivity MR_aggregateOperation:@"sum:" onAttribute:@"duration" withPredicate:activityOfInterestPredicate];
    NSLog(@"The sum of all the durations for the activity of interest is %zd", activityOfInterestDurationTotal);

    benchmarkActivityDurationTotal = [TimedActivity MR_aggregateOperation:@"sum:" onAttribute:@"duration" withPredicate:benchmarkActivityPredicate];
    NSLog(@"The sum of all the durations for the benchmark activity is %zd", benchmarkActivityDurationTotal);

    [self doTheMathAvsA];

}

-(void) doTheMathAvsA
{
    // Get the total and respective percentages of the totalled durations from the criteria distilled in handleAvsAAction

NSNumber *total;
total = (activityOfInterestDurationTotal + benchmarkActivityDurationTotal);

}
```

**Edit:** modified `doTheMathAvsA` to clarify the desired result.

All help or suggestions appreciated!

**Second edit:**

OK, your answer below makes sense, and thanks @Martin R!

However, the two quantities in question here originate as `NSTimeInterval`s, and as mentioned above, are stored as attributes of type `double`, on an entity called `TimedActivity`.

So, it seemed rational to me to slightly rewrite the code to extract them from the persistent store as `NSTimeInterval`s, which I am assured are really just doubles. However, when I do this, I get this error:

```
Assigning to 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double') from incompatible type 'NSNumber *'
```

Here are the modified declarations:

```
NSTimeInterval activityOfInterestDurationTotal;
NSTimeInterval benchmarkActivityDurationTotal;
```

And here's where the error appears:

```
activityOfInterestDurationTotal = [TimedActivity MR_aggregateOperation:@"sum:" onAttribute:@"duration" withPredicate:activityOfInterestPredicate];
NSLog(@"The sum of all the durations for the activity of interest is %@", activityOfInterestDurationTotal);

benchmarkActivityDurationTotal = [TimedActivity MR_aggregateOperation:@"sum:" onAttribute:@"duration" withPredicate:benchmarkActivityPredicate];
NSLog(@"The sum of all the durations for the benchmark activity is %@", benchmarkActivityDurationTotal);
```

OK, I assume that the `NSNumber` referred to in the error message is this property in the `TimedActivity` managed object subclass, auto-generated from the data model:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * duration;
```

So my question becomes:

Is it really necessary to resort to such seemingly ever-widening circles of conversion and retro-conversion to perform such a seemingly simple calculation? Or am I missing a more straightforward solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to compute, and give a concrete example of input data and the expected output?

Comment: And note that there should be no single quotes in `predicateWithFormat:@"name == '%@'"` .

Comment: Sure. Please see edit above. The two inputs are in the form of doubles, as explained earlier. Expected output would be an NSNumber (total), representing the sum of the two said variables. Good tip on the single quotes.

Comment: Here's what get when I try the doTheMathAvsA method as written:  "Invalid operands to binary expression ('NSNumber *' and 'NSNumber *')"

Comment: Please see second edit above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot perform arithmetic directly on `NSNumber` objects. The easiest solution is
to convert them to `double` for the addition:

```
double tmp = [activityOfInterestDurationTotal doubleValue] + [benchmarkActivityDurationTotal doubleValue];
```

and the result back to `NSNumber`, if necessary:

```
NSNumber *total = @(tmp);
```

---

*Update:* By default, the Xcode generated accessor methods use Objective-C objects even
for primitive Core Data types such as "Double". You can change that by selecting the
"Use scalar properties for primitive data types" option when creating the subclass files.
Then a "Double" property is declared as

```
@property (nonatomic) double activityOfInterestDurationTotal;
```

and you can access it "directly" as for example

```
NSTimeInterval duration = thisActivity.duration;
```

because `NSTimeInterval` is just another name for `double`.

*But* there is another problem: The MagicalRecord "convenience method" `MR_aggregateOperation:` uses a special fetch request with `NSDictionaryResultType` to
fetch the sum of all `duration` values. And even if you chose to use a scalar property
for the duration, the result of `MR_aggregateOperation:` is always some Objective-C object, in this case `NSNumber`, there is no way around it.

So the only way to avoid a conversion between `NSNumber` and `double` would be to use a scalar
property as described above, and instead of using `MR_aggregateOperation:`, fetch all
objects and add the `duration` values yourself in a simple loop.

But note that the fetch request with the aggregate operation performs the calculations
on the SQLite level, this is probably more effective then actually fetching all objects.

Comment: @TimJones: I have extended the answer, hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks very much, @Martin! It's still a messy situation, but I believe you've given me the tools to plot a course. I've had good luck with MagicalRecord, so I'll deal with the conversions. Thanks again, sir! A green check and an up vote for you!